# compare two columns in the same table and update a new column with results

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have one table called table1 
It has two fields called "name1" and "name2" 
I want to compare these two columns with each other
and if name1 has a value that is not exist in name2 I want to know that to fill with a new flag column and vice versa

```
table1 : 
----
name1  name2
----
jack   wheile
--
james  jack
--

>        
sample output : 
--
name1  name2   flag
--
jack   wheile  jack exist in column2
--
james  jack    jack exist in column1
--
```

any help ?

Comment: What will be the `flag` field for the row (jack,jack) ?

Comment: yes or any name exist in coloumn 1 and coloumn 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET FLAG = CONCAT('exist in ', IF(NAME1 LIKE '%jack%', column1, column2)) 
WHERE NAME1 LIKE '%jack%' OR NAME2 LIKE '%jack%';
```

Comment: Sorry about that, this is mysql sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

This query should achieve the required result if executed from within Access itself

```sql
UPDATE table1 SET
    flag = Switch(DCount("*", "table1", "[name2]=""" & Replace([name1], """", """""") & """")>0, [name1] & " exists in column 2", DCount("*", "table1", "[name1]=""" & Replace([name2], """", """""") & """")>0, [name2] & " exists in column 1")
```

Edit:

Alternatively, the following approach could prove to be considerably more efficient but would require two UPDATE queries

```sql
UPDATE table1 SET flag = [name1] & " exists in column 2"
WHERE 
    [name1] IN
        (
            SELECT x.name1 
            FROM 
                table1 AS x 
                INNER JOIN 
                table1 AS y 
                    ON x.name1 = y.name2
        )
```

and

```sql
UPDATE table1 SET flag = [name2] & " exists in column 1"
WHERE 
    [name2] IN
        (
            SELECT y.name2 
            FROM 
                table1 AS x 
                INNER JOIN 
                table1 AS y 
                    ON x.name1 = y.name2
        )
```